# hash_pbkdf2 vs password_hash PHP functions

Tags: php, security, php-password-hash

As PHP 5.5.0 is out now,

1. Which one is better to use (security, portability, future proof)?
2. It says the password_hash() **PASSWORD_DEFAULT** may change in each full release (+1.0 or +0.1) so how can we use previously DEFAULT method hashed password with new default? does that mean PHP 5.5 scripts with already hashed passwords in database will not work on PHP 5.6 until users change their passwords? what about ***COST*** change ***(i'm trying to know if servers can be updated to php v5.6, or website admin may change the hosting provider (and then change COST for weaker/stronger servers), without any problem for current users)***
3. Should we wait for some updates or are they already safe to use in 5.5.0
4. Should we still use PHPass etc frameworks or these new PHP 5.5 functions are enough and/or more future proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The [password hashing functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) (such as `password_hash`) are preferred, as they automate more of the process, such as picking a salt, verifying passwords, and rehashing.
2. The [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function will automatically detect what algorithm was used to generate a hash, so there's no compatibility issue.
3. These functions are in a released version of PHP, so they should be fine to use.
4. Use PHPass or a shim such as [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) if your code needs to run on versions of PHP earlier than 5.5. Otherwise, use the password hashing functions.

Answer (score 4):

The new function `password_hash()` is just a wrapper around the function `crypt()` and simplifies its usage. The crypt function returns hashes of this form:

```
 algorithm (BCrypt)
 |  cost factor (10)
 |  |  salt                  hash-value
 |  |  |                     |
 -- -- -----------------------------------------------------
$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
```

This means that the algorithm and all parameters are included, which are necessary to compare an entered password with the stored hash-value. Even if the default algorithm would change, the function `password_verify()` will be able to recognize the used algorithm, and can use the older algorithm to verify the password.

So this new password API is surely the most future-proof way to hash your passwords. You can even use it with older PHP versions with the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).